# Is there any way to prevent Freestyle from wasting time calculating objects that were excluded from rendering?

Tags: performance, freestyle

I love making animations that use high amounts of reflective surfaces, and recently have been trying my hand at Freestyle which is amazingly fun.

In my current project, I am trying to make only one object be Freestyle-d, which was easily achieved through Layers. Or so I thought, until I realized that the separate layer rendering did not play well with the reflective surfaces. Rendering as one layer, and keeping the exclusions for all objects except main, worked as expected.

However, it seems the Freestyle render still calculates to topology (topography?) of all other objects in scene, despite being excluded in the line style settings. With just my main character object, render times are only a few seconds per frame, and a few seconds for the freestyle. With the secondary character, render times are again only a few seconds, with well over a minute per frame as it refuses not to calculate the excluded objects. This problem only seems to get exponentially worse as objects are introduced.

That brings me to my question - For a highly reflective scene in which all objects are being reflected and interacting, and thusly don't seem (to me) to retain proper reflectivity in multiple layer renders, is there any way to prevent the Freestyle render from wasting time calculating other objects?

Comment: I'm confused  in what you are asking, if you want reflected objects, the reflections have to be calculated.  Freestyle is a postprocess, in the sense that needs to generate the geometry of the scene, in order to work.